# Json parser issues to get all actor value into the arraylist

Tags: android, json

use json jason parser but i am not adding multiple tag values into the arraylist and i want to parse $t tag with Actor into the arraylist.such as

```
{
"media$group":{
"media$credit":[
{
"$t":"Murison Dunn",
"role":"Writer",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Randolph Scott",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Forrest Tucker",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"name":"Mala Powers",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"J. Carrol Naish",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Edgar Buchanan",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"name":"Myron Healey",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Howard Petrie",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"name":"Ray Teal",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"William Forrest",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Denver Pyle",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Trevor Bardette",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Kenneth Tobey",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
}
]
},

{
"media$group":{
"media$credit":[
{
"$t":"Murison",
"role":"Writer",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Scott",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Tucker",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
}
{
"name":"Powers",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
}
]
},

{
"media$group":{
"media$credit":[
{
"$t":"Dunn",
"role":"Writer",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"J.Naish",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Buchanan",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Healey",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
},
{
"$t":"Petrie",
"role":"Actor",
"scheme":"urn:ebu"
}
]
}
}
```

However my main issue is that I need to get multiple items from $t tag into the arraylist. and my code is:

```
JSONObject jsonmediagrop=videoObject.getJSONObject("media$group");
 JSONArray itemsmediarole = jsonmediagrop.getJSONArray("media$credit");
            for(int l=0;l<itemsmediarole.length();l++){
                JSONObject Objectrole = itemsmediarole.getJSONObject(l);

                strrole=Objectrole.getString("Role");
                Log.v("Role", strrole);

                if(strrole.equals("Actor"))
                { 

                     stractor=Objectrole.getString("$t") + "," + stractor;
                     Log.v("stractor", stractor);
                     maprole.put("$t", stractor);
                     myrolelist.add(maprole);
                }

            }
```

myrolelist -this is the arraylist. maprole-this is the hashmap. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what issue you are facing currently ?

Comment: the json array is  not valid

Comment: when i am add all actor from json array into the arraylist but find these value such as 1st array have all 12 actor name and 2nd have 12+3=15 actor and 3rd have 15+4=19 .but i want into the arraylist 1st have 12 and 2nd have 3 and 3rd have 4 actor name only .this is my  issue bro.

Comment: please check your json array in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Kenneth Tobey,Trevor Bardette,Denver Pyle,William Forrest,Ray Teal,Howard Petrie,Myron Healey,Edgar Buchanan,J. Carrol Naish,Mala Powers,Forrest Tucker,Randolph Scott-this is first tag data and second one is- Kenne Duncan,Adrienne Dore,Charles Starrett,Kenneth Tobey,Trevor Bardette,Denver Pyle,William Forrest,Ray Teal,Howard Petrie,Myron Healey,Edgar Buchanan,J. Carrol Naish,Mala Powers,Forrest Tucker,Randolph Scott...here first three data is second array but this is also add array first data into second array

Comment: @vabhavsingh : i see your api but in json response we are not getting any name tag so i think you will need to change `Objectrole.getString("name")` to `Objectrole.getString("$t")`

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/movies/most_recent?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=5&paid-content=false&hl=en&movie-genre=1&alt=json    this is the youtube api webservice and i want all actor name from media$grop tag then enter media$credit tag then get all actor name

Comment: i mean $t is name tag thnx fro quick response bro

Comment: and i changed $t but array add value all first into second then second value add into third,then next but i want first in fist ,second in second ,third in third

Comment: @vabhavsingh : try as replace `maprole.put("name", stractor);` with `maprole=new HashMap<String,String>(); 
maprole.put("name", stractor);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after reading your comment in the other answer, I decided to help you.
I had lots of problems parsing mine too. Went through lots of researches
In my code I was trying to get the `rstp url links`.
I hope you can look at it and solve your problem.
This is my working code

```
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        String entry = obj.getString("entry");
        JSONObject enObj = new JSONObject(entry);
        String group = enObj.getString("media$group");
        JSONObject grObj = new JSONObject(group);
        String content = grObj.getString("media$content");
        JSONArray array = grObj.getJSONArray("media$content");
        for(int j=0; j<array.length(); j++){
            JSONObject thumbs = array.getJSONObject(j);
            String url = thumbs.getString("url");
            urls[j] = url;
            Log.d(TAG, url);
            //data.setThumbUrl(thumbUrl);
        }


        Log.v(TAG, content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

For you this may do the trick:

```
   try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        String entry = obj.getString("entry");
        JSONObject enObj = new JSONObject(entry);
        String group = enObj.getString("media$group");
        JSONObject grObj = new JSONObject(group);
        JSONArray array = grObj.getJSONArray("media$credit");
        for(int j=0; j<array.length(); j++){
            JSONObject credits = array.getJSONObject(j);
            String role = credits.getString("role");
            Log.d(TAG, role);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: thanx for response bro.but i want all actor name from $t tag

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. As i scroll down your JSON list, you have defined arrays of same name. That is why it is taking multiple values of key "role".

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/charts/movies/most_recent?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=5&paid-content=false&hl=en&movie-genre=1&alt=json .this is the youtube api webserivice and i want to all actor name from media$group tag

Comment: Your JSON is okay. Lazy Ninja has posted code for you. It will work perfectly as per your JSON. +1 for him.

Comment: bro i want all $t value into the arraylist for related actor role tag

Comment: first of all, get the the value of role tag, if it is string put the value of "$t" into your arraylist.

Comment: but i declare above code but some mistake in my logic to add first array data into the second array and second array data add into the third array...how to solve it bro

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21748/discussion-between-rohit-and-vabhavsingh)